# Java - replace all non-ASCII but leave HTML special characters

Tags: java, regex

If I have a String

```
String mine = "Some Name &reg; plus encoding issue ????? \u0000 something ";
```

I would like to keep all the ASCII characters and HTML entities, but remove any other encoding.

I tried

```
mine.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```

but this removes things like trademark and copyright

Is there a way to keep the HTML entities but remove all other encoding?

Comment: _but this removes things like trademark and copyright_ - these are not in the ASCII range. Generally, you can filter by range or category but you will have to be more specific about which [code points](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) are allowed and which are not. Around 250K code points have been assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Normalize` and `EscapeHtml` to achieve it, with a fair amount of accuracy:

```
String mine = "site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép";
mine = Normalizer.normalize(mine, Normalizer.Form.NFD); // Normalize with Canonical decomposition
mine = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(mine); // Escape the html values now
System.out.println(mine); // Would be - site design / logo &copy; 2014 stack exchange inc; árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép

mine = mine.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
mine = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(mine); // Unescape
System.out.println(mine); // site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; arvizturo tukorfurogep
```

[Normalize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) with canonical decomposition would map the accented characters (in this case) with their, well, canonical decomposition values. (link provides for an excellent resource for that)

[StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) is a handy utility class with escape/unescape `htmls, csvs, xmls`.

Hence, I first use the NFD to normalize the String to evade the `escapeHtml3` process (else each accented char would be replaced by its accented counterpart).

Now when I escape Html, `copyright` symbol gets escaped without affecting the accents. After removing the non-ascii part, accented are replaced by their counterparts but `copyright` is still escaped, which I can easily revert with the `unescapeHtml3` back to its original form.

You an go through the respective links to gain more perspective about the behavior which I have tried to exploit in this case.

Comment: This is nice. What do the Normalize and EscapeHtml do? Which one converts the acented characters?

Comment: @sln I have updated the post with the details and the links, basically `Normalize` is a significant class which provides for a great way to normalize Strings in Java. `StringEscapeUtils` has pretty handy utility methods to work the htmls, xmls etc

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\\p{ASCII}` property:

```
mine = mine.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]+", "");
```

OR else use `\\P{ASCII}`:

```
mine = mine.replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}+", "");
```

Comment: This is U+0000 to U+007F